# Criando uma animação JS com SVG usando HTML e CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Estou começando os estudos com SVG e tentando compreender um exemplo não consigo executá-lo corretamente, foram demonstradas as partes HTML/CSS/JS e eu fiz a conexão dessas partes, porém não funcionou... Se alguém puder me falar o que estou fazendo errado seria de muita ajuda:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Exemplo Teste</title>
    <style>
      .meu-circulo {
        r: 30;
        cx: 50;
        cy: 40;
        fill: lightgreen;
        stroke: orange;
        stroke-width: 5;
        transition: all 1s ease;
      }

      .meu-circulo:hover {
        cx: 70;
        fill: green;
        stroke-width: 10;
      }

    </style>
    <script>
      const circle = document.querySelector('.meu-circulo');
      let r = 30;

      circle.addEventListener('click', () => {
        r += 10;
        circle.style.r = r;
      })

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <svg>
      <circle class="meu-circulo"></circle>
    </svg>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Mas o que foi que não funcionou??

Comment: Não desenhar o circulo e aplicar o efeito JS de aumentar o raio com o evento de click

Answer (score 1):

O problema acontece porque quando é chamada a linha:

```
const circle = document.querySelector('.meu-circulo');
```

O elemento:

```
<circle class="meu-circulo"></circle>
```

Ainda não existe gerando o erro:

> cannot read property of undefined

Na linha:

```
circle.addEventListener('click', () => {
```

Para resolver o problema coloque o script dentro do evento ['load'](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/load) do documento ou seja seu script só será acionado depois que página carregar.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Exemplo Teste</title>
  <style>
    .meu-circulo {
      r: 30;
      cx: 50;
      cy: 40;
      fill: lightgreen;
      stroke: orange;
      stroke-width: 5;
      transition: all 1s ease;
    }
    
    .meu-circulo:hover {
      cx: 70;
      fill: green;
      stroke-width: 10;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {


      const circle = document.querySelector('.meu-circulo');
      let r = 30;

      circle.addEventListener('click', () => {
        r += 10;
        circle.style.r = r;
      })
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg>
      <circle class="meu-circulo"></circle>
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```